# Tomcat JDCBRealm not finding driver class

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, intellij-idea, hsqldb

I'm using hsql as my database backend and I wanna configure JDBCRealm for authentication/authorization. I'm using Intellij for development and deployment and Tomcat 7.

This is my `context.xml`:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
           driverName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
           connectionURL="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost"
           userTable="customers" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
           userRoleTable="roles" roleNameCol="role_name"/>
</Context>
```

and I've added hsqldb as a library :

[image]

When I deploy the application, the JDBCRealm does not find the added driver:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:688)
```

But to ensure that the aformentioned class can be loaded properly, I added this snippet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Class foo = Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("This is working!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As it is expected, by requesting the proper URL resulting in the servlet being executed, the server prints `This is working` indicating that the class which `JDBCRealm` had not found, is loaded properly.

Any idea what the problem is?
I have only two clues that might relevant ( or possibly irrelevant ! ) :

1. some of my added libraries including `hsql` is not added to `target/WEB-INF/lib`:

[image]

But the question is : If it is not added as library in the target, so how the previous snippet was working?

**Workaround**

Although I have no idea why `JDBCRealm` is not finding the `HSQLDriver` , but by copying its JAR file to `/var/lib/tomcat7/lib` where is one of the places that catalina loads JARS, the problem got solved. But it's still mystery for me how to fix the problem in a standard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you've chosen is the standard way: The Realm is running outside of your application, thus it can't depend on the code that is introduced with your application - it *must* choose the global classpath.

If it would rely on code from your webapp, this would actually introduce an interesting attack vector, where your app is responsible for its own authentication: Not the intention of the authors, thus this is the situation you'll have to cater for.

Answer (score 2):

Your workaround isn't a workaround. It *is* the standard way.

See the documentation of [`JDBCRealm`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm):

> **Quick Start**
>
> To set up Tomcat to use JDBCRealm, you will need to follow these steps:
>
> 1. If you have not yet done so, create tables and columns in your database that conform to the requirements described above.
> 2. Configure a database username and password for use by Tomcat, that has at least read only access to the tables described above. (Tomcat will never attempt to write to these tables.)
> 3. **Place a copy of the JDBC driver you will be using inside the `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory.** Note that only JAR files are recognized!
> 4. Set up a `<Realm>` element, as described below, in your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` file.
> 5. Restart Tomcat if it is already running.

That is because the Realm is managed outside the webapp, even if it only applies to a single Context.